# Compiling OpenBIOS for Sparc cross compiling

Tags: makefile

I am trying to compile the OpenBIOS application downloaded from the github repository

```
git clone https://github.com/openbios/openbios.git
```

However I come across the following error message

```
grct@grct-Dell-DM061:~/openbios$ ./config/scripts/switch-arch sparc32 sparc64 amd64
Configuring OpenBIOS on amd64 for sparc32 sparc64 amd64
Initializing build tree /home/grct/openbios/obj-sparc32...ok.
Creating target config.mak...ok.
Creating target rules.mak...ok.
Creating config files...ok.
Initializing build tree /home/grct/openbios/obj-sparc64...ok.
Creating target config.mak...ok.
Creating target rules.mak...ok.
Creating config files...ok.
Initializing build tree /home/grct/openbios/obj-amd64...ok.
Creating target config.mak...ok.
Creating target rules.mak...ok.
Creating config files...ok.
grct@grct-Dell-DM061:~/openbios$ make
/usr/bin/xsltproc
Building OpenBIOS for sparc32 sparc64 amd64
Building...
ok.
ok.
error:
 HOSTCC host/kernel/stack.o
 HOSTCC forthstrap
  GEN   bootstrap.dict
  GEN   openbios.dict
  GEN   openbios-amd64.dict
  GEN   openbios-unix.dict
  CC    target/arch/unix/unix.o
/home/grct/openbios/arch/unix/unix.c: In function ‘read_from_disk’:
/home/grct/openbios/arch/unix/unix.c:420:2: error: ignoring return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Werror=unused-result]
  read(diskemu, buf, size);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
rules.mak:209: recipe for target 'target/arch/unix/unix.o' failed
make[1]: *** [target/arch/unix/unix.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/grct/openbios/obj-amd64'
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I dont know how to overcome this error? Any help I can get is appreciated

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try finding and removing `-Werror` from the makefiles.

Comment: OK It can compile using your method. But it means certain binaries are not compiled. This is what happens when I try to execute OpenBIOS using the 'make run' command....

Comment: 'code ' grct@grct-Dell-DM061:~/openbios$ make run
Running...
/bin/sh: 2: /home/grct/openbios/obj-sparc32/openbios-unix: not found
/bin/sh: 2: /home/grct/openbios/obj-sparc64/openbios-unix: not found
Welcome to OpenBIOS v1.1 built on Apr 9 2019 11:00
  Type 'help' for detailed information
[unix] Booting default not supported.
Trying disk...
No valid state has been set by load or init-program
0 > 'code'

Comment: I suspect my Xubuntu OS is missing dependencies. But I dont know which ones it needs? :(